# ASP.NET MVC Identity vs ASP.Net core 2.1 Identity (Cross authentication between them)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have two different projects one for a web application which is in Asp.Net MVC using EF code first and another for mobile application APIs which is in Asp.Net Core 2.1 using EF code first, both are sharing the same database both are using Identity authentication. The problem is if someone registered with web application and trying to login with APIs with identity authentication. It unable to authenticate because user registered with ASP.Net MVC Identity and APIs have Asp.Net Core Identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which code solves the problem but I don't think the problem's source is there. However, if you use the same process in different areas, you can face a lot of problems. Appearing of this problem is normal because of the codes containing the same logic place in multiple locations.

I think you need to have a new application that serves services to both applications. Then you can move the same code in both applications into the new application. On the result, codes containing the same logic are collected in only one place.

[image]